# How to fold camembert in dough

Tags: baking, cheese, dough

Every time I bake camembert in bread dough, I do a bad job of enveloping. Usually, I make a thin dough circle (like a pizza base) with diameter somewhat less than three times the camembert's diameter. I put the camembert in the middle and the herbs, nuts and spices evenly on top of the camembert. Then I gather the dough sides up and make a bundle. I roll the bundle between my hands until it is smooth. After a short time for a last rising, it goes into the oven.

What I don't like in the method above is that I end up with lots of doufgh atop the camembert. I'd like a uniformly thin(fnish) crust around the cheese. So for dinner today, I decided to improve.

I formed a camembert sized concave dough shell. I put the camembert into the shell, put the spices on top, then made a camembert sized dough circle and placed it on top. I pressed the seam to glue it shut, then gave it a smooth shape. Again some raising, and then I put it into the oven seam side up. Sadly, the seam must have opened in the oven, and most of the mildly expensive cheese has flown out. It is 11:40 pm and my dinner is ruined ;(

Does anybody know a practical way of enveloping the camembert so there is no risk of a seam opening, and the dough is evenly distributed?

Comment: I usually just close the seams like your failed attempt, and haven't had that issue. It may help to get the seams on top of cheese rather than on the sides.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I know this is an old post but just in case anyone else is stuck with the same problem, I found this worked for me.

Roll out the dough so it's roughly 3x diameter, place the camembert in the middle. Fold two opposite sides over the top of the camembert. Then with the remaining unfolded sides, fold one on top and one underneath.

You're still left with a little more on top than underneath, but it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here's a bit of a math geek answer. I have NOT tried wrapping and baking camambert, but I think this will fix your problem.

Try your original method, but roll the dough out so that the radius is twice the radius of the cheese (instead of three times). When you go to "wrap" the cheese up, the dough will not reach the center of the cheese...but that's ok, because you have the excess dough from the folds to make up the difference. Does that make sense? Roll the bundle in your hands, as you mentioned before.